# Can the core dump cause memory leak?

Tags: linux, ulimit

I recently did this to my system

```
ulimit -c unlimited
```

and it created as designed, a core file for the program I use, ever since, I have had random crashes to my program but I haven't had the possibility to check the core dump to see what errors it gave, as it does daily restart of the program, I assume the previous errors are gone, if they are not, please tell me so I can look them up.

But my question is: is there in any possible way that this new ulimit command I used, be the issue with the server crash? because for years ive runned the same program with no crashes and since this commmand, I have had random crashes from time to time that somewhat feels like it loops for around 5 minutes then restarts the program.

Any help is appreciated, as I cannot reproduce the issue

Comment: If you program is automatically restarting itself, are you sure that it has not crashed in the past? The only difference now is that it requires time to create a core dump.

Comment: Never, these type of crashes now can happen randomly. Example: in 1 week, I get this crash perhaps 1 day, and it can happen at 12am, then it restarts after 5 minutes, happens at 14 pm again. This only happen after I did the ulimit -c unlimited, so I wonder if it perhaps leaks out of memory when writing the core file as the core file comes up to 2.5 gb (thus the reason why it takes 5 minutes before the restart), just a theory.

Comment: Core is written by kernel, no userspace code is executed (I mean code of your program) while it is written, so your hypothesis is very unrealistic.

Comment: As I use a shell for the program in use, my theory was simply that within the shell, the writing process "lags" either the computer or shell and makes the program exit (not neccessarily crash). Because I noticed during this incident, the website was not accessible either, simply loading and not working. I might be wrong, I just try to figure out if there is a possibility for a program to be overheated due to the writing process, just as mentioned in the point that even the web server stops reacting.

Comment: But:a memory leak *could* lead to a core dump. (I don't know which signal the kernel sends on an OOM)

Comment: @wildplasser AFAIK the OOM killer sends `SIGKILL`; no dump.

Comment: I think it is SIGABRT

Comment: Maybe both  (with a grace period inbetween)? I don't know, my code never leaks;-]

Comment: Ed Heal, was that an answer to my question or to wildplasser?